# QGIS fails to load WMS layer

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities

I am trying to load WMS from the URL https://vedas.sac.gov.in/geoserver/vedas/wms/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

While this URL works on the website https://vedas.sac.gov.in/desertification/index.html, it does not work when I use the URL in QGIS 3.22.12. QGIS throws an error: 'Failed to parse capabilities.'

The error report marks the error in the requested XML at line 27817. Is there any way to still access the layer without the server admin deleting the said layers?

```
Could not get WMS capabilities: invalid name for processing instruction at line 27817 column 21
This is probably due to an incorrect WMS Server URL.
```

Comment: Not a QGIS issue, issue is all on the GeoServer server for having an invalid response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WMS 1.3.0, take a copy of the XML output, delete the corrupted `forest_biomass_karnataka` layer and add `</Layer></Capability></WMS_Capabilities>` to the end of the file.  The file is still invalid at this point though.  Several `Style` sections are missing required `Title` elements, such as `vedas:rh_forecast`, `vedas_dvi:aizwal_pie`, `India_wetland_2017_18`, `vedas:rh_forecast` there are others... you can add in an empty element `<Title/>`

A couple of `eastBoundLongitude` elements have values greater the 180, which is not permitted, so change those to 180.

Now you have a valid capabilities response, but you should go further.

Change all `http://192.168.2.17:8090/` references to `https://vedas.sac.gov.in/` except the `GetCapabilities` URL at: `/WMS_Capabilities/Capability[1]/Request[1]/GetCapabilities[1]/DCPType[1]/HTTP[1]/Get[1]/OnlineResource[1]/@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' and local-name()='href']` which should point to your saved capabilities file on your local server, for example I changed mine to `http://localhost/test/verdas130.xml`

[image: Service works in QGIS]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very large and horrible capability response document that generates a Java exception on output. But if you download the xml File and replace lines  **27815**-**27820** with the following lines, it may be possible to load some layers if you drag the file into map canvas.

```
27815:    </Layer>
27816:  </Capability>
27817:</WMT_MS_Capabilities>
```

Comment: I did do this on my own and tried to load the same in QGIS just before coming here again.  Got a new error: The file is not a WMS connections exchange file. Is that cause the last closing tag should be </WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1" updateSequence="459904">instead of the plain </WMT_MS_Capabilities>?

Comment: No </WMTS_MS_Capabilities> is enough. But you can check the XML with gdalinfo as well. In OSGeo4W Shell enter "gdalinfo <your XML file>".